# Split string PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-split

I have never understood the pattern of regular expression and after googling I haven't been any wiser.

I want to grab the WordPress version number (3.2) from this string:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.2" />
```

In the future when upgrading to 3.3 I wan't the split code to be able to get that to. So no static expression.

How do I solve this?

Comment: The proper way would be to use a [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php/3577662#3577662), even though it might seem like overkill for the task

Comment: It might be overkill, but it would be a lot more reliable in the long run. If WP changes whitespace or what have you, the regex could break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regular expression that works for this...

```
$str = '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.2" />';
preg_match('/meta name="generator" content="WordPress [0-9]+\.[0-9]" /', $str, $matches);
preg_match('/[0-9]+\.[0-9]/', $matches[0], $matches1);
$version = $matches1[0];
echo "Wordpress version is = $version";
```

It should output this:

> Wordpress version is = 3.2

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.2" />';
$pat = '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress (\d*\.?\d*)" />';
if(($match = preg_match($pat, $data)) !== false){
    echo $match[1];
}else{
    echo "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('|<meta name="generator" content="WordPress (.*?)" />|', $where_to_search_for, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's pretty old question, and out of curiosity, why don't you just use builtin function to retreve the WordPress version being used?

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'version' );?>
```

This way, even the Generator meta is removed, you will get the exact version from `$wp_version` var.